# Using for..of with Map generates invalid ES5

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

I'm having an issue using the latest TypeScript 1.5 compiler in conjunction with `Map` and `for..of`. Example:

```
var map: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();
map.set("A", "one");
map.set("B", "two");
map.set("C", "three");
for(let [key, value] of map) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/03/27/announcing-typescript-1-5-alpha.aspx), TypeScript 1.5 supports destructuring and for..of so I can't really see why this shouldn't work, but it outputs invalid ES5:

```
for (var _i = 0, _a = map; _i < _a.length; _i++) {
//                              ^^^^^^^^^
// A Map doesn't have a length, so this block never executes
    var _b = _a[_i], key = _b[0], value = _b[1];
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

I worked around this by using `map.forEach((value, key) => { ... });` but it's not as nice as `for..of`.

Is this a limitation of the 1.5 release? Am I expecting it to transpile `Map` to ES5 when it's not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `for of` that is supported by TypeScript with targets ES3/5, is very limited. Iterables need the target ES6.

> Is this a limitation of the 1.5 release?

Yes:

> This works for arrays and strings. Other iterables will not be supported for ES3/ES5 [(Source)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/2207#issuecomment-77513924)

Comment: But, no regret. [The code generated by Babel for a `for of` statement is ugly because of iterators](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=false&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=const%20arr%20%3D%20[%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27]%3B%0Afor%20%28let%20val%20of%20arr%29%0A%20%20console.log%28val%29%3B%0A).